# AngularJS : Interpolating attributes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-compile

Say I have the following two directives:

```
angular.module('foo').directive('outer', [function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      inner: '@',
      innneParams: '@'
    },
    template: "<div {{inner}}{{innerParams}}></div>",
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
      console.debug("I AM IN YOUR OUTER DIRECTIVE PASSING YOUR D00DZ!")
    }
  }

}]);
angular.module('foo').directive('innerDir', [function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: {
      innerParam: '='
    },
    template: "<div>{{massagedInner}}</div>",
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
      console.debug('I AM IN YOUR INNER DIRECTIVE MASSAGING YOUR D00DS!')
      scope.massagedInner = scope.innerParam + "FROM YOUR DOGE!"
    }
  }
}]);
```

And the following HTML:

```
<outer inner="inner-dir" my-awesome-scope-value="myAwesomeScopeValue" inner-params="inner-param='myAwesomeScopeValue'"></outer>
```

The outer directive console debug triggers, the inner one does not. Is there a good way for me to achieve this kind of behaviour?

Plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/jXbtWvYvtFXCTWiIZUDW?p=preview

Comment: You're trying to use a directive as attribute (the inner one) but you restricted it to `E` (element only). You need to restrict the inner directive to attribute also: `EA`, let's say. You're also having an ending single quote typo here: `my-awesome-scope-value="myAwesomeScopeValue'`.

Comment: Those were both problems, however the inner-param still doesn't bind.... updated plunk/question to address your points

Comment: I don't think you can define a template twice on the same element. You have the outer and inner both competing to do so. You're also requesting isolate scope twice. The inner one looks it should be an element directive but I'm not clear what your objective is.

Comment: Apart from being full of typo bugs (sometimes the param name is `inneParams` sometimes it is `innerParam` sometimes it is `innerParams`) I think you are hitting on the problem of sibling scopes; that is, the inner and outer are actually side-by-side in scope hierarchy instead of nested as assumed here....I'd verify that.

Comment: My apologies for the bugs. I've cleaned them up

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few things you're doing wrong. I've made the changes that I thought are close to what you wanted it to do and you can change the code from here.

[Here's a working version](http://plnkr.co/edit/9HMcgMfphg5LOie0CdbK)

And this is what `script.js` now looks like;

```
angular.module('foo', []);
angular.module('foo').controller('fooController', ['$scope', function(scope){
  scope.myAwesomeScopeValue = 'O HAI THERE'  
}]);
angular.module('foo').directive('outer', [function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      // inner: '@',
      // innnerParams: '@'
      innerParam: '@'
    },
    template: "<div inner {{inner}} {{inner-param}}></div>",
    link: function (scope) {
      console.log('OUTER', scope.innerParam);
    }
  }

}]);
angular.module('foo').directive('inner', [function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    // scope: {
    //   innerParam: '='
    // },
    replace: false,
    template: "<div>{{massagedInner}}</div>",
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
      scope.massagedInner = scope.innerParam + "FROM YOUR DOGE!"
      console.log('INNER');
    }
  }
}]);
```

For brevity, I've left some of your lines commented out. I hope this helps.

Comment: This doesn't really do what I want since the inner directive is applied unconditionally, not passed through from the parent scope

Comment: AFAIK, there's no way to conditionally apply directives, yet. The condition for that must live above the directives; `ngIf` may help, but ofcourse, it has to be on the directives rather than in them.

The idea here was to show that you don't need to isolate scopes on all directives – especially when you have two or more directives working on the same element. Its quite possible for a child directive to use the parent scope – in this case the `inner` directive uses `outer`'s scope, which can in turn use the parent scope if `replace: false`.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf